# SQL Show items that don't exist in other categories

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a table of Tier, Category and Items.  For Tier = 2, each Category should have the same # of items. I want to display the items that are missing from each category.

Here is a sample table:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Items') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Items
CREATE TABLE #Items (
    Tier        int,
    Category    nvarchar(25),
    Item        nvarchar(25)
)

INSERT INTO #Items
SELECT '2', 'CategoryA',    'Item1'
UNION ALL
SELECT '2', 'CategoryA',    'Item2'
UNION ALL
SELECT '2', 'CategoryA',    'Item3'
UNION ALL
SELECT '2', 'CategoryB',    'Item1'
UNION ALL
SELECT '2', 'CategoryB',    'Item3'
UNION ALL
SELECT '2', 'CategoryC',    'Item1'
UNION ALL
SELECT '2', 'CategoryC',    'Item2'
UNION ALL
SELECT '2', 'CategoryC',    'Item3'
UNION ALL
SELECT '2', 'CategoryC',    'Item4'

SELECT
    Tier,
    Category,
    Item
FROM #Items
ORDER BY Tier, Category, Item

Tier    Category    Item
2   CategoryA   Item1
2   CategoryA   Item2
2   CategoryA   Item3
2   CategoryB   Item1
2   CategoryB   Item3
2   CategoryC   Item1
2   CategoryC   Item2
2   CategoryC   Item3
2   CategoryC   Item4
```

If I show a count of items in each category:

```
SELECT
    Tier,
    Category,
    COUNT(Item) as ItemCount
FROM #Items
GROUP BY Tier, Category
```

They should all have the same 4 items:

```
Tier    Category    ItemCount
2   CategoryA   3
2   CategoryB   2
2   CategoryC   4
```

I want to display a list of the items that are missing from each category.  This could works but is obviously clumsy and just to present the data how I would like to see it.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    Tier,
    'CategoryA' as [Category],
    Item
FROM #Items i
WHERE Item NOT IN (SELECT Item from #Items WHERE Category = 'CategoryA')
UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT
    Tier,
    'CategoryB' as [Category],
    Item
FROM #Items i
WHERE Item NOT IN (SELECT Item from #Items WHERE Category = 'CategoryB')
UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT
    Tier,
    'CategoryC' as [Category],
    Item
FROM #Items i
WHERE Item NOT IN (SELECT Item from #Items WHERE Category = 'CategoryC')
```

And shows the results:

```
Tier    Category    Item
2   CategoryA   Item4
2   CategoryB   Item2
2   CategoryB   Item4
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do that with a cartesian product of items, then pull out the ones that don't exist in the source table:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    i1.Tier,
    i1.[Category],
    i2.Item
FROM Items i1, Items i2
WHERE i2.Item NOT IN (SELECT Item from Items WHERE Category = i1.Category)
```

Results:

```
TIER    CATEGORY    ITEM
----    --------    -----
2       CategoryA   Item4
2       CategoryB   Item2
2       CategoryB   Item4
```

You can [test the query here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/bb1ac/3).

Comment: Learning new things like this makes me want to learn more new things like this :)  Thanks

Comment: It's quite slow when you have a lot of records.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this with a cross join and then left joining it back to itself:

```
select
     _Categories.category
    ,_Items.item
from(
  select distinct
      category
  from Items
) _Categories
cross join (
  select distinct
      item
  from items
) _Items
left join Items _ActualItems
  on _ActualItems.category = _Categories.category
  and _ActualItems.item = _Items.item
where _ActualItems.item is null
```

Here is a [SQL Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/bb1ac/11) of this.